# Client Side WebSocket connection, fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, websocket, chat

I am working on ReactJS chat app
when i am trying to make connection to the node server, I get an error in the console that the connection failed

##### This is the Client side app

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from 'websocket';

const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000');

export default class App extends Component {
  onButtonClick(message) {
    client.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        type: 'message',
        msg: message,
      })
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    client.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    };

    client.onmessage = message => {
      const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(message.data);
      console.log('Got Reply : ' + dataFromServer);
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.onButtonClick('Hello');
          }}
        >
          Send Message
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

##### this is the error i've got

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wRpo.png)

##### here is the server side app

```
const webSocketServerPort = 8000;

const webSocketServer = require("websocket").server;

const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(webSocketServerPort, () => {
  console.log(`WebSocket server is running on port ${webSocketServerPort}`);
});

const wsServer = new webSocketServer({
  httpServer: server,
});

const clients = {};

function getUniqueID() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
}

wsServer.on("request", (request) => {
  var userID = getUniqueID();
  console.log(
    new Date() +
      " Recieved a new connection from origin " +
      request.origin +
      "."
  );

  const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

  clients[userID] = connection;

  console.log(
    "connected: " + userID + " in " + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(clients)
  );

  connection.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.type === "utf8") {
      console.log("Recieved Message: " + message.utf8Data);

      for (key in clients) {
        clients[key].sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
        console.log("sent Message to: " + clients[key]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

according to the tutorial i am following it is supposed to connect successfully but i don't know what is the problem

Comment: The triangle right in front of the error message suggests that there's more information to be seen...